# Migrating from On-Premises File Server to Azure

Tags: azure

Today i have a Physical Machine running Windows Server 2008 that servers File to all my employees, so i have a On-Premises File Server.

This **On-Premises File Server** have a lot of rules based on my Active Directory Server. i.e: Folder "financial" only can be accessed by users in group "manager".

Now i want to migrate this to files to some service in azure cloud, so after some searching i found following options: Blob Storage and File Storage. I think File Storage is ideal for my business but i have some doubts:

1. Can i apply Active Directory rules in File Storage ? I have AD Sync enable in my azure account.
2. File storage is better solutions for my case ? If no, what is the other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the closest you can get is using the Azure AD Domain Services ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq#security-authentication-and-access-control), [another link](https://www.petri.com/azure-ad-authentication-for-azure-files))
2. File storage is definitely a better solution, blobs are not really meant to be accessed like a file server.

You might want to look at Azure File Sync, while its not what you ask for exactly, it's pretty close.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/score-one-for-the-it-pro-azure-file-sync-is-now-generally-available/

Comment: Do you think a good solution create a Azure VM install AD e files and controle everything ?

Comment: that would be one way to do it, but certainly not a PaaS one

Comment: I'm thinking about the following: Create a VM just for file storage and connect this VM to my On-Premises AD, this is possible? (P.S: I have Azure AD + Azure AD Domain Service enabled)

Comment: yeah, its just a vm in azure, create a site-to-site and you can add it to domain

Comment: Hey, about using file sync, the azure keep all my files on-premises ? If I have 4TB in cloud?

Comment: I think you can pick what files to sync, but I'm not exactly sure, sorry

Comment: Another solution is create a simple web interface to manage access to azure files using rest. What do you think about it?

Comment: usually paying a little extra is cheaper than having to implement a service on top of another service and maintain that service. I'd (personally) would avoid implementing  a service for that